# Unable to get my custom play button to work on my video player

Tags: javascript, video, custom-controls, video-player

I'm trying to make a custom video player, but I'm running into an issue when I try using Javascript to make the video play and pause.  I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null at togglePlayPause

Here's my Javascript.  ".video" is my video player, ".orange-juice" is my progress/time bar, and "play-pause" are my play and pause buttons.

I'll also mention that I tested with an alert() and it seemed to work, so I'm not quite sure what I've got wrong.

```js
// VIDEO

var video = document.querySelector(".video");
var juice = document.querySelector(".orange-juice");
var btn = document.getElementById("play-pause");

function togglePlayPause() {
  if (video.paused) {
    btn.className = "pause";
    video.play();
  } else {
    btn.className = "play";
    video.pause();
  }
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  togglePlayPause();
};
```

Comment: your `video` variable, points to a dom element, that does not have a `pause()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to find the elements you've listed. Essentially it is clicking on nothing. You need to address those elements and their respective classes/id.

```
<video class="video orange-juice" />
<button id="play-pause">Play/Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, but I got it figured out.  Turns out I was missing my .video class in my html (always that one little thing).  All is working fine now.  Thanks!